# Building a grid of equal square polygons in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, vector-grid

Not having them depend on decimal degrees, but on a certain distance.

When I use a tool it asks me the length of the cell in degrees, but I want all sides of every cell to be equal and with degrees it always makes rectangular cells or different lengths.

Comment: What tool are you using?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with both the [Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) tool or the [Grid Index Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/grid-index-features.htm) tool.

Create Fishnet is a bit more configurable, and can output either polygon or polyline.  Both will allow you to set a width and height.

Answer (score 3):

I will also recommend a free tools developed by [Jenness Enterprises](http://www.jennessent.com/arcgis/repeat_shapes.htm)

It is just in case you need to use other shapes or point grids.